# Run specific test file through command prompt

Tags: junit, command-prompt

i am trying to run a test project through command prompt.
Say **calculator** is my main project to which i have written a test project as **calTest**
now calTest has many java files like **addTest.java** and **subTest.java**. How do i run only addTest.java through command prompt??

```
android update test-project -m ~calculatorpath -p .
```

I used above command to build the test project with my present working directory as calTest directory.

```
ant debug install test
```

I used this to run the test project ,it runs both the java files. But i want only one java file to run. how do i do this ? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your problem following link will help you more to have clear picture

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html